# how pass Boolean data to another page(which does not have a direct page route)

Tags: android, flutter, dart

i just wanted to pass whether bool isSelected true or false to the third page.
please help me somebody
(the code is large. that's why i'm not sharing)

Comment: how are you creating a new `Route`? tried to read [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation) cookbook?

Comment: Please share the essential code.

Comment: If you're going to use the property in multiple views, create a Singleton Class and read the value from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to create a `public static` boolean variable in your `MainActivity` and you can read value of that boolean variable from any other activities using this syntax `MainActivity.(variableName)`